# Conditional CSS for Svelte, but with dynamic values

Tags: svelte

As I am diving into making many UI components for my Svelte apps, it seems like it’s really hard to avoid inline styling, especially when it comes to dynamic values like width, background-color, or font sizes. It’s no big deal as the guide seems to do so (https://svelte.dev/tutorial/dimensions), but not very pleasant to see all the inline styling in the HTML. I also thought of using style variables(https://svelte.dev/repl/bb42c17d585b4236824e1d5e48fe92b5?version=3.38.0), but it gets complicated as the component gets larger, and complex.

I looked up on the HTML of documentation on the Sveltekit website. Surprisingly, they don’t have any inline CSS, all is the classes, well-organized, no inline styling whatsoever. Is there something I am missing form the documentation? I want to know how they would even make it possible to zip the dynamic values into the classes, never use the inline styling.

Answer (score 0):

You might have some wrong assumptions here. You can look at the source code of the SvelteKit documentation [on Github](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/tree/master/sites/kit.svelte.dev); there is nothing particularly special about it.

It mostly uses CSS variables, toggles various classes with `class:` or just has *hard coded values* in the classes.

Here are two example rules from the search:

```css
label {
    color: #666;
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 0.9rem);
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    pointer-events: none;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    animation: fade-in 0.2s;
}

kbd {
    display: none;
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 0.2rem 0.2rem 0rem 0.2rem;
    color: #666;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

There is nothing dynamic about this.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have found out, using CSS variables is the most convenient way. It gets complicated the more variables you have of course, but I haven't found any cases where I needed more than a couple for one element. What is really nice is that variables are inherited to child elements, so you don't need to duplicate variables, e.g. for sibling elements.

If you really don't want to put the variables in the element, you can do something like:

```js
$: document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color', `${color}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

cascading-jox's answer is much more concise, but I have recently made a library for this based on the way that they did his answer (except with JSON): [svelte-styling](https://npmjs.com/package/svelte-styling)

For raw styles:

```html
<script>
  import { styles } from "svelte-styling"
  let border = "1px black solid"
</script>

<input use:styles={{ border }} bind:value={border} placeholder="Enter Border">
```

For variables:

```html
<script>
  import { variables } from "svelte-styling"
  let size = 1
  let backgroundColor = "white";
</script>
<input type="number" bind:value={size} placeholder="Enter Size">
<p use:variables={{ size }}></p>

<input type="number" bind:value={backgroundCOlor} placeholder="Enter Background Color">
<svelte:body use:variables={{ color: backgroundColor }}>

<style>
  :global(body) {
    --color: white;
    background-color: var(--color);
  }

  p {
    --size: 1; /* default SSR value! */
    font-size: calc(var(--size) * 2rem);
  }
</style>
```

[Demo](https://leodog896.github.io/svelte-styling)